# How to edit the mosquitto.conf in a mosquitto Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, mosquitto

I have a linux system running with several Docker containers. One of them is mosquitto container which runs from mosquitto 1.6.7 docker image.

I do not have control how the Mosquitto container is created as it is given by default from a supplier/client.

I need to make changes in the `mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf` file. This is the output when I run `ls -l`

```
/mosquitto/config # ls -l
total 4
-rwxrwxr-x    1 nobody   nobody         210 May 24 05:35 mosquitto.conf
```

I tried the codes below to add a comment in the `mosquitto.conf`, but I am not successful.

```
/mosquitto/config # echo '#test' | su nobody -c 'tee -a mosquitto.conf'
nologin: this account is not available
/mosquitto/config # echo '#test' | su nobody -s sh -c 'tee -a mosquitto.conf'
su: can't execute 'sh': No such file or directory
/mosquitto/config # echo '#test' | su nobody -s bin/sh -c 'tee -a mosquitto.conf'
su: can't execute 'bin/sh': No such file or directory
/mosquitto/config # echo '#test' | su nobody -s /bin/sh -c 'tee -a mosquitto.conf'
tee: mosquitto.conf: Permission denied
#test
```

Is it possible to change the `mosquitto.conf`?

If yes, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

You make a copy of it on the host machine, edit there and then mount that edited copy into the container when you start it.

e.g.

```
docker run -d -v /path/to/local/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf mosquitto
```